# consolidate and migrate multiple kafka clusters to 1 cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

I have 2 onprem kafka clusters on 2 environment dev and test (they have the same topic names). Now I want to consolidate them into only one cluster (aws msk). I would like my new kafka cluster to have both environment topics. They will be differentiated by the prefix  in their names. Example: dev_topicA, test_topicA. Is that posible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with MirrorMaker2:

- run a connector of MirrorSourceConnector with properties `source.cluster.alias=dev` and source cluster bootstrap servers to dev cluster
- run another connector of MirrorSourceConnector with properties `source.cluster.alias=test` and source cluster bootstrap servers to test clusters
- in both connectors use target cluster bootstrap as your MSK cluster

The default replication naming policy is the one to add aliases.

Default separator is `.`. If you would like to have `_` like in your example, override default separator: `replication.policy.separator=_`